# How to filter a collection using LINQ to DataSet

Tags: c#, linq, dataset, linq-to-dataset

I'm working with a `DataSet` that contains two tables that I am trying to get data out of via LINQ.

I'm struggling with figuring out the syntax of how to return records that meet a condition.

Example:

**Here are the two tables:**

[image: FooBar Items]

[image: FooBar Data]

**This query joins the two tables** (Item Z will be filtered out)

```
private void ParseFooBar()
{
 ....
 var fooBars = from item in fooBarItems 
      join data in fooBarData on item["FooBar_Id"] equals data["FooBar_Id"]
      where (new[] {"A","B","C"}).Contains(item["id"])
      select new
      {
      id = item["id"],
      description = item["description"],
      wat = data["wat"],
      foo = data["foo"]                 
      };
}
```

**This is the collection that was derived from the above query.**

[image: FooBar Items joined with FooBar Data]

**Question: How do I return Foo items only?**

Notice how the Foo items have in their first row/record a non-null value while the Bar items do not have a non-null value in the first row/record. Using the fact that all Foo items will have at least one non-null in the foo column and Bar items will never have a non-null value in the foo column, how can I update the above query so that the query only returns Foo items? Likewise, how can I update the query so that it only returns Bar items?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what the criteria are for being a Foo versus a Bar, but here are a few ideas:

```
var foos1 = fooBars.Where(fb => fb.wat != "bar");
var foos2 = fooBars.Where(fb => fb.wat == "foo" || fb.wat == null);
var foos3 = fooBars.Where(fb => fb.wat == "foo" || fb.foo != null);
var bars = fooBars.Where(fb => fb.wat == "bar" || fb.foo != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you want to filter unwanted `nulls` out. If at the joining level, you can slightly alter your query:

```
from item in fooBarItems 
join data in fooBarData on item["FooBar_Id"] equals data["FooBar_Id"]
where (new[] {"A","B","C"}).Contains(item["id"]) && data["foo"] != null
select new
{
   id = item["id"],
   description = item["description"],
   wat = data["wat"],
   foo = data["foo"]                 
};
```

This will return only two elements:

- `A, I am a Foo, null, 10834`
- `B, I am a Foo, null, 08385383`

To get remaining ones (including those where `foo` *is* `null` yet they belong to Foo which has a non-null entry), use combination of `.GroupBy` and `.Where` after your main query:

```
fooBars
    .GroupBy(f => f.id)
    .Where(g => g.Any(f => f.foo != null))
    .SelectMany(g => g); // just to make it nice list-like looking
```

This will select entire groups, but only those which have *at least* one `foo` with non-null value (which would be all entries from final collection, except those with `id = C`).

Comment: I like your idea with the appended lambda - it looks like it would work, but it doesn't. The result of your updated query returns a collection no different than the original. Strange.

Comment: @Jed: oh, made a typo. Should be `f.foo != null`, not `""`. Fixed now.